# How do I re-position this menu in CSS?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, zurb-foundation

I am modifying the CSS/HTML code from a template that places navigation buttons above the banner image, which is in the background. The template also uses media queries to change the look and position of the navigation buttons as the browser window shrinks.

My main problem is moving the navigation menu to the right side of the banner image. The position of the menu is set to "relative" top: 0, left: 0. When I move the menu to the left 20 pixels, the reduced version of the menu also moves to the left 20 pixels.

I am interested to know the best way to position the menu to the right in desktop view without moving the menu in tablet and mobile view.

1. I am using Foundation 5 columns.
2. The menu and banner image are nested within a 12-column div.
3. The menu has a z-index of 1000, which places it above the banner.
4. Floating the menu puts the banner image out of position.

Thank you for your help!

CSS:

```
 #banner-nav0 {
 width:23%;
 background: url(white80.png) repeat;
 height: 357px !important;
 }

 #banner-nav {
 z-index:100;
 list-style: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 }

 #banner-nav li a {
 font-size: 1.1em;
 border-bottom:1px solid #FFFFFF;
 color:#4d4f53!important;
 display:block;
 font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;
 font-weight:normal!important;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-shadow:0 1px 1px #FFFFFF;
 padding:5%;
 }

 #banner-nav li a:hover,#banner-nav li a:active {
 background:url(img/common/home-slider-current.jpg) no-repeat;
 background-color: #4d4f53;
 color:#FFF!important;
 text-shadow:0 1px 1px #000;
 } 

 .banner-wrapper {margin-top: -357px !important;}

 #banner-nav li img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  left: 6%;
  } 

 /* MEDIA QUERIES */ 

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 900px) {
#banner-nav0 {
width: 100%;
height: 20px !important;
position: relative; 
left: 0px; 
top: 0px;
}

#banner-nav li {
display: inline-block;
margin: 5px;
}
#banner-nav li a {
font-size: 1.6vw;
padding: 0.3em 0.5em !important;
}
#banner-nav li a:hover {
border-radius: 5px;
}
.banner-wrapper {margin-top: 25px !important;
}
#banner-nav li img {
display: none;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
.banner-wrapper {display: none;}
#banner-nav0 {
width: 100% !important;
height: auto !important;
position: relative; 
left: 0px; 
top: 0px;
}
#banner-nav {width: auto;}
#banner-nav li a {
font-size: 3vw;
padding: 5px;
}
#banner-nav li img {
display: none;
}
}
```

HTML

Sidebar column area

```
<section class="large-9 columns">

    <div class="large-12 columns">

        <div id="banner-nav0" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 0px; z-index: 1000">
                <ul id="banner-nav">
                <li><a href="#" title="How to Apply">How to Apply</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Course Modules">Course Modules</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Resources">Resources</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="For Faculty">For Faculty</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="banner-wrapper">
                    <img src="Banner2.gif" alt="IPC Banner">
            </div>
    <!--   <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">            
            </div>
    </div> -->
    </div>
```

Comment: can you add your banner image? Your code just contains its name.

Comment: @Haoyu Chen - Added the banner image.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'll just post an answer I guess.

You want to position the table differently depending on what device is viewing it? Have you thought of just applying different classes to the menu if the device is mobile?

For example, this would assign a class to an element if the screen width was under 699px -

```
 <script>
        window.onload = "functionzero()"
        {
            if (screen.width <= 699) {
            var elem = document.getElementById("menu");
            elem.className = "mobile"; }
        }
    </script>
```

Then you could just have the class ".mobile" and edit it to your liking.